# Multiplicative modular group is internal direct product of subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $U(st)$ be the multiplicative modular group mod$st$ where $s,t$ are relatively prime integers.

Let $U_s(st)=\{x \in U(st)\mid x \pmod{s}=1\}$, $U_t(st)=\{x \in U(st)\mid x \pmod{t}=1\}$

Show that $U(st) =U_s(st) \times U_t(st)$

Attempt:
Since the group is abelian, any subgroups or normal.

I know that because $s,t$ are relatively prime $U_s(st) \cap U_t(st)=\{1\}$ however I do not know how to show this. Letting $x \in U_s(st) \cap U_t(st), x=1\pmod{s},x=1 \pmod{t}\implies x=1$. But I am not very confident why?

Comment: If $x-1$ is a multiple of both $s$ and $t$ then $x-1$ is a multiple of their least common multiple, which is $st$. Hence $x-1$ is congruent to zero modulo $st$ which means that $x$ is congruent to $1$ modulo $st$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Use the *Chinese Remainder theorem*: we have a *ring* isomorphism
$$\mathbf{Z}/st\mathbf Z\simeq\mathbf Z/s\mathbf Z\times \mathbf Z/t\mathbf Z,$$
hence…